# How to add new template to existing java class

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-tool-suite

I have a Spring Boot Application in Spring tool suite. I have a template that I want to apply on this project to get copyright header and other default stuff.

I did import as show in the below image. Now I am not sure how to apply on existing Java classes. My new classes are picking up the template but not the existing files.

[image]

How can my existing classes in my project pick up this template. I tried source format. It didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

The code templates are used for new classes/files only, not for existing classes. You can use a different tool.

For example Eclipse Releng Tools, described here: https://wiki.eclipse.org/Development_Resources/How_to_Use_Eclipse_Copyright_Tool

or:

http://www.codejava.net/ides/eclipse/how-to-add-copyright-license-header-for-java-source-files-in-eclipse

Or Copyright Wizard, as described here:
https://www.mkyong.com/eclipse/how-to-add-copyright-to-eclipse-automatically/

Hope this helps!!!